# Rails - how to have all views in a controller be bound to routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I'm very new to Rails. I have this controller called static_pages, wherein there are different views (hotel, cafe, museum). I'm currently doing this in the routes.rb

```
match '/school',    to: 'static_pages#school',    via: 'get'
match '/hotel',    to: 'static_pages#hotel',    via: 'get'
match '/museum',   to: 'static_pages#museum',   via: 'get'
match '/peace', to: 'static_pages#peace', via: 'get'
match '/cafe',  to: 'static_pages#cafe',            via: 'get'
match '/investor',  to: 'static_pages#investor',            via: 'get'
```

How do I get to do "if in static pages controller, bound the view name to a specific URL". Something to remove these 6 lines and just turn them into 1 line where it says that for each method in the controller, generate a route.

Are there special tricks to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

routes.rb is a regular ruby file so you could do something similar to

```
['school', 'hotel', 'museum', etc].each do |route|
  match route, to: "static_pages##{route}", via: 'get'
end
```

if you want to shorten it.

edit:

If you want to get all the methods instead of hardcoding, you could do this:

```
(ControllerName.methods - ActiveRecord::Base.methods).each do |route_sym|
  match route_sym.to_s, to: "static_pages##{route_sym.to_s}", via: 'get'
end
```

Comment: It is okay although I was thinking of readability in mind. I will probably stick with the normal way, but it was nice to learn about the second solution